# Running over files in a directory creates an extra nan array

Tags: python, numpy, operating-system, genfromtxt

I'm using the following for loop that runs over a directory that contains a few files with a list of numbers (nodes).

```
for filename in os.listdir(nodes_path):
    nodes_arr = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(nodes_path, filename), delimiter=',')
    print (nodes_arr)
    print (len(nodes_arr))
```

In this example I have 4 files in the directory.
I've set the path to it in `nodes_path`.
The problem is I'm getting a 5th string that contains `nan`.
output:

```
[22718045.  1172884.  1434416. ... 84287109. 84328117. 84381796.]
219463
[6.9590000e+03 7.7180000e+03 1.3373000e+04 ... 8.3828038e+07 8.4007117e+07
 8.4046414e+07]
63309
[56467551. 12073526. 12655638. ... 84299018. 84312857. 84388811.]
271456
[81614683. 11760788. 15679375. ... 84431649. 84448307. 84458895.]
274465
[nan nan nan nan]
4
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: when adding `dtype=None`, i got the metadata of the folder: `[b'[.ShellClassInfo]' b'InfoTip=This folder is shared online.'
 b'IconFile=C:\\...\\googledrivesync.exe'
 b'IconIndex=16']` this is what creates the `nan` array. but how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:
Excluding the last file from the for loop as follows:

```
for filename in os.listdir(nodes_path)[:-1]:
DO ...
```